# Does utilizing the Windows User Interface API risk incompatibility between different versions of Windows?

Tags: winapi, ui-automation

I am working on a C# Excel VSTO add-in that utilizes the user32.dll to do some black magic with the excel UI.  I am not very experienced in using Win32, and I am wondering:

Do I need to worry about ensuring that the application works on all versions of Windows from XP and after?  Or is it reasonable to assume that my Win32 calls will work consistently in all these versions?

**Edit:** here are the calls I am using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static public extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hChild, string strClassName, string strName);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static public extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static public extern bool IsWindowEnabled(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Comment: In former times one could assume this, yes. But thanks to SxS (side-by-side) it is possible that multiple versions of the same library (e.g. common controls) are used on a system. However, it is exceedingly difficult to use more than one of these library versions in the same process. It is possible with dirty hacks, though. Without knowing the calls involved, the question is *impossible* to answer.

Comment: Microsoft also put a hell of a lot of effort into application compatability and NOT breaking API cals between version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, the calls you are using are *not* going to go away just like that, they're here to stay. However, especially `FindWindowEx` has a very specific functionality, so it is very possible that you are trying to find a child window in the Excel GUI whose name and/or window class can change any time (including via minor updates) at the discretion of Microsoft.

So to answer your question: no need to worry about the API functions you are using, but yes you will have to code defensively in order to make sure your code doesn't misbehave on Excel versions that don't fulfill the expectations (about the presence of particular child windows) in your code.

Comment: +1. Using any undocumented method to do something is very likely to break at any time. You should investigate official, documented methods in the Excel API to do what you require.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already confirmed the VSTO API doesn't provide the functionality I require.  This is my last resort.  Now that I have been assured that that Win32 API is reliable/compatible, I can focus on handling the scenario that FindWindowEx doesn't find the expected result.